# Не хочет отображать фон ячейки таблицы

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!
Проблема. Некоторые браузеры отказываются показывать фон столбца в таблице. К этим некоторым относятся Chrome, Opera  и Maxthon 3. Почему-то мне кажется, что проблема в их современном движке. Код таблицы вот такой:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="120" width="100%" style="background:#0006FF;border-right:1px solid #000000;">
<tr>
 <td width="310" height="120" style="background:url('/new/logo.png') no-repeat;"></td>
 <td align="center" style="background:url('/new/topmenubg.png')" class="topLink"></td>
 <td width="16" style="background:url(/new/topmenubg_end.png) no-repeat"></td>
 <td width="200" style="background:url(/new/topinfobg.png) no-repeat"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Из этого отказывается показывать фон вот этого столбца:

Ну в чем проблема? Хоть убейте меня, но ошибок не вижу! Или что-то обновилось, а я не знаю об этом? Помогите!

Comment: Не отображается фон второго столбца

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь вы не [письмо](http://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/) верстаете )))

> Не стоит использовать CSS свойства для наложения фона, они будут
>   игнорироваться некоторыми почтовыми клиентами:
>
> ```
> background: 
> background-image:
> background-position:
> background-size:
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="120" width="100%" style="background:#0006FF;border-right:1px solid #000000;">
<tr>
 <td width="310" height="120" style="background: transparent url('/new/logo.png') top left no-repeat;"></td>
 <td align="center" style="background: transparent url('/new/topmenubg.png') top left no-repeat;" class="topLink"></td>
 <td width="16" style="background: transparent url('/new/topmenubg_end.png') top left no-repeat;"></td>
 <td width="200" style="background: transparent url('/new/topinfobg.png') top left no-repeat;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Это полный синтаксис бэкграунда, так точно будет работать, если картинки есть на сервере. Можете попробовать какие-то параметры поубирать, когда заработает.

Comment: Неа, не помогает =(

Comment: для table пропишите стиль "empty-cells: show;"